# Continuously encounter "write /dev/stdout: copy_file_range: bad file descriptor" in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, filesystem, compiling

It happens when I use `sudo apt-key update`

root@xxx:/# apt-key update
2021/09/01 14:51:22 write /dev/stdout: copy_file_range: bad file descriptor

And it also happens many times when I'm trying to build PHP:

`php7.2.34/configure`

output just like:

```
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... 
 <--it's too long I moved it to a new line-->
2021/09/01 14:44:13 write /dev/stdout: copy_file_range: bad file descriptor
no
checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC
checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC works...
2021/09/01 14:44:13 write /dev/stdout: copy_file_range: bad file descriptor
yes
checking if cc static flag -static works... yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... 
2021/09/01 14:44:13 write /dev/stdout: copy_file_range: bad file descriptor
yes
checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared 
libraries... yes
```

I have googled & checked "write /dev/stdoud: copy_file_range: bad file descriptor", but most of discussions are on their self project, I don't know why even `sudo apt-key update` will result in such an error.

Any clue or suggestion?

regards

---

Here's output of `strace apt-key update` under root user:

```
execve("/usr/bin/apt-key", ["apt-key", "update"], 0x7ffd1f2ba4f8 /* 31 vars */)
= 0
brk(NULL) = 0x560fcc21a000
arch_prctl(0x3001 /* ARCH_??? */, 0x7fffb8bc66f0) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=99260, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 99260, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f761550d000
close(3) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\360q\2\0\0\0\0\0"...,
832) = 832
pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"...,
784, 64) = 784
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\5\0\0\0GNU\0\2\0\0\300\4\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0",
32, 848) = 32
pread64(3,
"\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0\t\233\222%\274\260\320\31\331\326\10\204\276X>\263"...,
68, 880) = 68
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2029224, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) =
0x7f761550b000
pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"...,
784, 64) = 784
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\5\0\0\0GNU\0\2\0\0\300\4\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0",
32, 848) = 32
pread64(3,
"\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0\t\233\222%\274\260\320\31\331\326\10\204\276X>\263"...,
68, 880) = 68
mmap(NULL, 2036952, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7615319000
mprotect(0x7f761533e000, 1847296, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f761533e000, 1540096, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC,
MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x25000) = 0x7f761533e000
mmap(0x7f76154b6000, 303104, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3,
0x19d000) = 0x7f76154b6000
mmap(0x7f7615501000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1e7000) = 0x7f7615501000
mmap(0x7f7615507000, 13528, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7615507000
close(3) = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f761550c580) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7615501000, 12288, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x560fca5e2000, 8192, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7615553000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f761550d000, 99260) = 0
getuid() = 0
getgid() = 0
getpid() = 4801
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {sa_handler=0x560fca5d7c30, sa_mask=~[RTMIN RT_1],
sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f761535f210}, NULL, 8) = 0
geteuid() = 0
brk(NULL) = 0x560fcc21a000
brk(0x560fcc23b000) = 0x560fcc23b000
getppid() = 4798
stat("/home/jiyrzhang/Desktop", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat(".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/bin/apt-key", O_RDONLY) = 3
fcntl(3, F_DUPFD, 10) = 10
close(3) = 0
fcntl(10, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0
geteuid() = 0
getegid() = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=0x560fca5d7c30, sa_mask=~[RTMIN RT_1],
sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f761535f210}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=~[RTMIN RT_1],
sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f761535f210}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=~[RTMIN RT_1],
sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f761535f210}, NULL, 8) = 0
read(10, "#!/bin/sh\n\nset -e\nunset GREP_OPT"..., 8192) = 8192
pipe([3, 4]) = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD,
child_tidptr=0x7f761550c850) = 4802
close(4) = 0
read(3, "\n\10", 128) = 2
read(3, "", 128) = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=4802, si_uid=0,
si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]}) = 0
close(3) = 0
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 4802
pipe([3, 4]) = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD,
child_tidptr=0x7f761550c850) = 4803
close(4) = 0
read(3, "", 128) = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=4803, si_uid=0,
si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]}) = 0
close(3) = 0
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 4803
pipe([3, 4]) = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD,
child_tidptr=0x7f761550c850) = 4805
close(4) = 0
read(3, "", 128) = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=4805, si_uid=0,
si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]}) = 0
close(3) = 0
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 4805
pipe([3, 4]) = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD,
child_tidptr=0x7f761550c850) = 4807
close(4) = 0
read(3, "", 128) = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=4807, si_uid=0,
si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]}) = 0
close(3) = 0
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 4807
pipe([3, 4]) = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD,
child_tidptr=0x7f761550c850) = 4809
close(4) = 0
read(3, "", 128) = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=4809, si_uid=0,
si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]}) = 0
close(3) = 0
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 4809
pipe([3, 4]) = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD,
child_tidptr=0x7f761550c850) = 4811
close(4) = 0
read(3, "", 128) = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=4811, si_uid=0,
si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]}) = 0
close(3) = 0
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 4811
read(10, "eys. so this check wouldn't\n "..., 8192) = 8192
read(10, "thout using gpg, just cat and fi"..., 8192) = 8192
pipe([3, 4]) = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD,
child_tidptr=0x7f761550c850) = 4812
close(4) = 0
read(3, "", 128) = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=4812, si_uid=0,
si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]}) = 0
close(3) = 0
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 4812
pipe([3, 4]) = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD,
child_tidptr=0x7f761550c850) = 4814
close(4) = 0
read(3, "TRUSTEDFILE='/etc/apt/trusted.gp"..., 128) = 35
read(3, "", 128) = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=4814, si_uid=0,
si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]}) = 0
close(3) = 0
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 4814
read(10, " really need a secret keyring af"..., 8192) = 3355
pipe([3, 4]) = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD,
child_tidptr=0x7f761550c850) = 4816
close(4) = 0
read(3, "", 128) = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=4816, si_uid=0,
si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]}) = 0
close(3) = 0
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 4816
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "gpg", X_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/sbin/gpg", X_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or
directory)
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/bin/gpg", X_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or
directory)
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/sbin/gpg", X_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or
directory)
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/bin/gpg", X_OK) = 0
pipe([3, 4]) = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD,
child_tidptr=0x7f761550c850) = 4818
close(4) = 0
read(3, "/tmp/apt-key-gpghome.DGtoTCHCJG\n", 128) = 32
read(3, "", 128) = 0
close(3) = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=4818, si_uid=0,
si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]}) = 0
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 4818
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {sa_handler=0x560fca5d7c30, sa_mask=~[RTMIN RT_1],
sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f761535f210}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {sa_handler=0x560fca5d7c30, sa_mask=~[RTMIN RT_1],
sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f761535f210}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGILL, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGILL, {sa_handler=0x560fca5d7c30, sa_mask=~[RTMIN RT_1],
sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f761535f210}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGABRT, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGABRT, {sa_handler=0x560fca5d7c30, sa_mask=~[RTMIN RT_1],
sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f761535f210}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGFPE, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGFPE, {sa_handler=0x560fca5d7c30, sa_mask=~[RTMIN RT_1],
sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f761535f210}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGSEGV, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGSEGV, {sa_handler=0x560fca5d7c30, sa_mask=~[RTMIN RT_1],
sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f761535f210}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {sa_handler=0x560fca5d7c30, sa_mask=~[RTMIN RT_1],
sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f761535f210}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {sa_handler=0x560fca5d7c30, sa_mask=~[RTMIN RT_1],
sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f761535f210}, NULL, 8) = 0
stat("/usr/local/sbin/chmod", 0x7fffb8bc5e20) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or
directory)
stat("/usr/local/bin/chmod", 0x7fffb8bc5e20) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or
directory)
stat("/usr/sbin/chmod", 0x7fffb8bc5e20) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/bin/chmod", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=63864, ...}) = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD,
child_tidptr=0x7f761550c850) = 4819
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 4819
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=4819, si_uid=0,
si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]}) = 4819
wait4(-1, 0x7fffb8bc5f9c, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
pipe([3, 4]) = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD,
child_tidptr=0x7f761550c850) = 4820
close(4) = 0
read(3, "gpg\n", 128) = 4
read(3, "", 128) = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=4820, si_uid=0,
si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]}) = 0
close(3) = 0
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 4820
pipe([3, 4]) = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD,
child_tidptr=0x7f761550c850) = 4823
close(4) = 0
read(3, "/tmp/apt-key-gpghome.DGtoTCHCJG\n", 128) = 32
read(3, "", 128) = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=4823, si_uid=0,
si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]}) = 0
close(3) = 0
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 4823
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/apt-key-gpghome.DGtoTCHCJG/gpg.0.sh",
O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
fcntl(1, F_DUPFD, 10) = 11
close(1) = 0
fcntl(11, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0
dup2(3, 1) = 1
close(3) = 0
write(1, "#!/bin/sh\nexec 'gpg' --ignore-ti"..., 174) = 174
dup2(11, 1) = 1
close(11) = 0
stat("/usr/local/sbin/touch", 0x7fffb8bc60e0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or
directory)
stat("/usr/local/bin/touch", 0x7fffb8bc60e0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or
directory)
stat("/usr/sbin/touch", 0x7fffb8bc60e0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/bin/touch", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=100728, ...}) = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD,
child_tidptr=0x7f761550c850) = 4826
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 4826
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=4826, si_uid=0,
si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]}) = 4826
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/apt-key-gpghome.DGtoTCHCJG/gpgoutput.log",
O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
fcntl(1, F_DUPFD, 10) = 11
close(1) = 0
fcntl(11, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0
dup2(3, 1) = 1
close(3) = 0
fcntl(2, F_DUPFD, 10) = 12
close(2) = 0
fcntl(12, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0
dup2(1, 2) = 2
stat("/usr/local/sbin/gpg", 0x7fffb8bc60c0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or
directory)
stat("/usr/local/bin/gpg", 0x7fffb8bc60c0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or
directory)
stat("/usr/sbin/gpg", 0x7fffb8bc60c0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/bin/gpg", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1066992, ...}) = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD,
child_tidptr=0x7f761550c850) = 4827
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 4827
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=4827, si_uid=0,
si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]}) = 4827
dup2(11, 1) = 1
close(11) = 0
dup2(12, 2) = 2
close(12) = 0
wait4(-1, 0x7fffb8bc601c, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
pipe([3, 4]) = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD,
child_tidptr=0x7f761550c850) = 4828
close(4) = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD,
child_tidptr=0x7f761550c850) = 4829
close(3) = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=4828, si_uid=0,
si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]}) = 0
close(-1) = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 4828
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 2}], 0, NULL) = 4829
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=4829, si_uid=0,
si_status=2, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]}) = 4829
wait4(-1, 0x7fffb8bc601c, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
ioctl(1, TCGETS, 0x7fffb8bc5dd0) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
fcntl(1, F_DUPFD, 10) = 11
close(1) = 0
fcntl(11, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0
dup2(2, 1) = 1
write(1, "Warning: apt-key output should n"..., 72Warning: apt-key output should
not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)
) = 72
dup2(11, 1) = 1
close(11) = 0
pipe([3, 4]) = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD,
child_tidptr=0x7f761550c850) = 4831
close(4) = 0
read(3, "0\n", 128) = 2
read(3, "", 128) = 0
close(3) = 0
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 4831
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=4831, si_uid=0,
si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]}) = 4831
wait4(-1, 0x7fffb8bc5f7c, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
pipe([3, 4]) = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD,
child_tidptr=0x7f761550c850) = 4832
close(4) = 0
read(3, "/tmp/apt-key-gpghome.DGtoTCHCJG\n", 128) = 32
read(3, "", 128) = 0
close(3) = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=4832, si_uid=0,
si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]}) = 0
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 4832
stat("/usr/local/sbin/rm", 0x7fffb8bc5d60) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or
directory)
stat("/usr/local/bin/rm", 0x7fffb8bc5d60) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or
directory)
stat("/usr/sbin/rm", 0x7fffb8bc5d60) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/bin/rm", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=72056, ...}) = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD,
child_tidptr=0x7f761550c850) = 4833
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 4833
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=4833, si_uid=0,
si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]}) = 4833
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD,
child_tidptr=0x7f761550c850) = 4834
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 4834
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=4834, si_uid=0,
si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]}) = 4834
wait4(-1, 0x7fffb8bc5a7c, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
stat("/etc/apt/trusted.gpg", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=28069, ...}) = 0
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/apt/trusted.gpg", R_OK) = 0
stat("/etc/apt/trusted.gpg", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=28069, ...}) = 0
pipe([3, 4]) = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD,
child_tidptr=0x7f761550c850) = 4835
close(4) = 0
stat("/usr/local/sbin/cmp", 0x7fffb8bc5860) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or
directory)
stat("/usr/local/bin/cmp", 0x7fffb8bc5860) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or
directory)
stat("/usr/sbin/cmp", 0x7fffb8bc5860) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/bin/cmp", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=51296, ...}) = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=4835, si_uid=0,
si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]}) = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD,
child_tidptr=0x7f761550c850) = 4836
close(3) = 0
close(-1) = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 4835
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 4836
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=4836, si_uid=0,
si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]}) = 4836
wait4(-1, 0x7fffb8bc573c, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
pipe([3, 4]) = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD,
child_tidptr=0x7f761550c850) = 4837
close(4) = 0
read(3, "/etc/apt/trusted.gpg\n", 128) = 21
read(3, "", 128) = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=4837, si_uid=0,
si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]}) = 0
close(3) = 0
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 4837
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/apt-key-gpghome.DGtoTCHCJG/pubring.gpg",
O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0666) = 3
fcntl(1, F_DUPFD, 10) = 11
close(1) = 0
fcntl(11, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0
dup2(3, 1) = 1
close(3) = 0
stat("/usr/local/sbin/cat", 0x7fffb8bc58a0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or
directory)
stat("/usr/local/bin/cat", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0775, st_size=3626835, ...}) = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD,
child_tidptr=0x7f761550c850) = 4838
wait4(-1, 2021/09/03 10:23:12 write /dev/stdout: copy_file_range: bad file
descriptor
[{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 1}], 0, NULL) = 4838
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=4838, si_uid=0,
si_status=1, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]}) = 4838
dup2(11, 1) = 1
close(11) = 0
wait4(-1, 0x7fffb8bc5f3c, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
stat("/tmp/apt-key-gpghome.DGtoTCHCJG/aptwarnings.log", 0x7fffb8bc5e70) = -1
ENOENT (No such file or directory)
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "gpgconf", X_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/sbin/gpgconf", X_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file
or directory)
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/bin/gpgconf", X_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or
directory)
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/sbin/gpgconf", X_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or
directory)
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/bin/gpgconf", X_OK) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
fcntl(1, F_DUPFD, 10) = 11
close(1) = 0
fcntl(11, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0
dup2(3, 1) = 1
close(3) = 0
fcntl(2, F_DUPFD, 10) = 12
close(2) = 0
fcntl(12, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0
dup2(1, 2) = 2
stat("/usr/local/sbin/gpgconf", 0x7fffb8bc6000) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or
directory)
stat("/usr/local/bin/gpgconf", 0x7fffb8bc6000) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or
directory)
stat("/usr/sbin/gpgconf", 0x7fffb8bc6000) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or
directory)
stat("/usr/bin/gpgconf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=178848, ...}) = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD,
child_tidptr=0x7f761550c850) = 4844
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 4844
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=4844, si_uid=0,
si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]}) = 4844
dup2(11, 1) = 1
close(11) = 0
dup2(12, 2) = 2
close(12) = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD,
child_tidptr=0x7f761550c850) = 4848
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 4848
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=4848, si_uid=0,
si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]}) = 4848
wait4(-1, 0x7fffb8bc61dc, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
exit_group(1) = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Comment: Could there be something wrong with `/dev/stdout`?  Please do `ls -l /dev/stdout` and add the output to your question. It should be something like `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 aug 31 20:40 /dev/stdout -> /proc/self/fd/1`.

Comment: I tried, the results just as you said. In addition, `echo something > /dev/stdout` will print it on screen.